# How to pass reference to the function

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I converted some VB Code to C# . Now I am stuck up at this point where I have to pass the parameters using **ref** keyword. The function is

```
CurrentZone.Radius = ModSoftUniversal.perirad(ref  (Z2 - Z1), ref ( Xval - Xinc - CurrentZone.Centerx), ref ( dXval - CurrentZone.Centerx), ref ErrorFlag);
```

The parameters in the function are doing some sott of calculation and to pass the values to the function , **ref** has to be used. 
Visual Studio shows the following [image]. I need help in passing the parameters

Comment: What would it even mean to pass the *result* of a calculation by reference? (Additionally, please post code *as text* rather than as screenshots - you can then post the error message as further text.)

Comment: declare the variables, do not do computation as parameters since it is reference parameters it needs a storage location for the value. ex.  int minusZ =  Z2 - Z1; then change do ref minusZ instead of (Z2 - Z1).

Comment: Couple of similar links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828842/a-ref-or-out-argument-must-be-an-assignable-variable
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307705/help-fixing-errors-in-c-sharp-a-ref-or-out-argument-must-be-an-assignable
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165892/passing-an-explicit-cast-as-a-ref-parameter-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass expression by reference. Add temporary variable like this:

```
var z = Z2 - Z1;
var x1 = Xval - Xinc - CurrentZone.Centerx;
var x2 = dXval - CurrentZone.Centerx;
CurrentZone.Radius = ModSoftUniversal.perirad(ref z, ref x1, ref x2, ref ErrorFlag);
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that attempting to pass `ref (Z2 - Z1)` may indicate that OP is misunderstanding what `ref` is doing. Adding a temporary may be hiding/throwing away an important calculation. `ref` doesn't make sense if the values can simply be thrown away.

Comment: Correct. But sometimes signature of the method requires value passed by reference, but result of modifications (if any) is not important for the caller. I believe author knows what he's doing and this is the case.

Comment: i knew this approach you mentioned but thought if it could work like this

Answer (score 2):

Make the code like this

```
var z1z2Result = (Z2 - Z1);
var xValxIncres = (Xval - Xinc - CurrentZone.Centerx);
var dxValResult = (dXval - CurrentZone.Centerx);

ModSoftUniversal.perirad(ref  z1z2Result, ref xValxIncres, ref dxValResult, ref ErrorFlag);
```

The reason is you can't make something byreference if it isn't assigned to a variable it can reference itself to

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a "expression" as `ref` or `out` parameter.

In C# `ref` parameter means that your parameter "reference" will be changed inside the function, and that's why you cannot pass a "expression".

You can read more about it, at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/14akc2c7.aspx

So, your code should look like that:

```
int Z3 = (Z2 - Z1);
int X1 = ( Xval - Xinc - CurrentZone.Centerx);
int X2 = ( dXval - CurrentZone.Centerx);
bool ErrorFlag = false;
CurrentZone.Radius = ModSoftUniversal.perirad(ref Z3, ref X1, ref X2, ref ErrorFlag);
```